# Python cmp() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, cmp

Hello I was trying to compare two tuples in python using the cmp() function
But there was an error wich is the following:

**NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined**

my Code:

```
myStupidTup = ("test",10,"hmm",233,2,"am long string")
mySmartTup = ("test",10,233,2)
print(cmp(myStupidTup, mySmartTup))
```

Comment: As the error message clearly states: `cmp` is not defined. What is your question?

Comment: `cmp()` function is only in python 2.x. `cmp()` does not work in python 3.x.

Comment: The built-in `cmp` function of Python 2 was dropped in Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`cmp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) function is only in `Python 2.x`. As mentioned in the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> The `cmp()` function should be treated as gone, and the `__cmp__()` special method is no longer supported. Use `__lt__()` for sorting, `__eq__()` with `__hash__()`, and other rich comparisons as needed. (If you really need the `cmp()` functionality, you could use the expression `(a > b) - (a < b)` as the equivalent for `cmp(a, b)`.)

The [`cmp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) equivalent in `Python 3.x` is:

```py
def cmp(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)
```

---

Note: Your tuples (`myStupidTup` and `mySmartTup`) don't support comparison. You will get a `TypeError` if you run it: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`